# In Visual Force Page not able make contact owner inlineEditable

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport, inline

I have a Visualforce page which displays `pageBlockSection` of Contact with  `mode="inlineEdit"`

```
 <apex:pageBlock title="{!contact.name}" mode="inlineEdit">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Information" >
  <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Name}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Primary_Languages_Spoken_VRM__c}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Choices_Offered__c}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Owner}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:pageBlock>
```

But I am not able to edit Name & Owner. I have checked Field Level accessibility - it is all editable for my profile. But why I am not able to edit in the VisualForce Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using **[apex:inputField](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm)** rather than **[apex:outputField](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputField.htm)**. As SFDC documentation states, outputField is...

> A read-only display of a label and value for a field on a Salesforce object.

What your VF page should look like is something like this:

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Information">
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Name}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Primary_Languages_Spoken_VRM__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Choices_Offered__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Owner}" />
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Information">
</apex:pageBlock>
```

---

**Edit #1**

Apparently, it is not possible to inline edit owner:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp6WAAS

However, you should be quite able to edit the Name of the Contact.

Comment: But mode="inlineEdit" should make it editable. I am able to edit Primary_Languages_Spoken_VRM__c & Choices_Offered__c.

Comment: Actually, I'm quite unclear how did you manage to edit anything, since you specified inlineEdit mode attribute on the pageBlockSection, when according to the doc it should be specified on pageBlock:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlock.htm

Comment: Sorry my mistake. it is in pageBlock. Edited my question.